# I wrote code exactly as shown from a Firebase tutorial and it doesn't work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

so here's the tutorial that I watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=865s
basically I'm trying to do local hosting of a webpage through Firebase and it keeps failing and this is the error I get on my BASH console.

```
i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
Warning: You're using Node.js v12.1.0 but the Google Cloud Functions runtime is only available in Node.js 6 (Deprecated), Node.js 8, and Node.js 10 (Beta). Therefore, results from running emulated functions may not match production behavior.
⚠  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory.
⚠  functions: Error from emulator. Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'consolidate'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

I did do npm install in my functions directory and I also did npm i --save firebase-functions inside my functions directory.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(
     functions.config().firebase

);

function getFacts() {
const ref = firebaseApp.database().ref('facts');
return ref.once('value').then(snap => snap.val());
}

const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s- 
    maxage=600');
    getFacts().then(facts => {
    response.render('index', { facts });
});
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Have you tried downgrading your node version to 8? It says in the warning message that functions runtime is not available in your node version. After downgrading you will also need to remove node_modules and run npm install again.

Comment: And you should run `npm run build` in my functions directory again.

Comment: I downgraded node version to 8 and reinstalled those things and then it works now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your 'functions' directory, run:

```sh
npm i handlebars consolidate --save
```

This will install both dependencies that you can then use by requiring them in your code.